# Incorrect Titles, Descriptions and Redirects in Google

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

I'm at a loss for why Google is indexing my site incorrectly. I just uploaded a new version of the site last night and "fetched as google" last night as well. Also uploaded sitemap.

www.lemonsevens.com
Search Term: lemon sevens

Still, though, for some reason google isn't displaying my title correctly and it is saying that it can't display the meta-description due to a blocked robot.txt (which isn't true). Help!?

Comment: Sorry but this type of question has been asked several times in various forms on Pro Webmasters, therefore making the question duplicate. But, to address your issue, is time. Google at some point in time has found a robots.txt or noindex in the page source, this may remove the description, meta and title but leave the page still indexed (but poorly ranked, unless you use the domain.com/path). When lifting robots block or no-index it takes Google some time to correct, this generally takes a few weeks.

Comment: Google fetch can help pages index quickly, however it doesn't correct these type of problems of pages that are not new and previously indexed as blocked. Also, your homepage is not even 'CACHED' yet which is another time flag... you just need to wait. As long as you ain't blocking via robots, or noindex it will resolve. Also, if Lemon Sevens is an important search phrase then you should include it in the meta description as currently it is not, otherwise Google may not return it.

Comment: You should also be aware that Google can 'REWRITE' titles, while I'm sure this isn't the case it does occur, for example on page /welcome-to-our-new-website/ its title is indexed 'Our New Website', even through that you have welcome to our new website in the title, its never a sure thing, Google often changes URL to the keywords people type in, also it can change from device to device. Stick around and your learn a lot on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: I did a *site:www.lemonsevens.com* to see what is going on. Google is picking up your links to these pages hence the SERP links however you are blocking these pages using your robots.txt file. Without getting into details, these are dangling links and only the link text is being used. Unblock the pages or use noindex on your pages to de-list these pages. Otherwise, unblock these pages and follow the advice I have given in many many answers on the title tag length, the h1 tag, and the description meta-tag. Cheers!!